# Let $f(x,y)$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x,y)$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)$, if for each y, $f(0,y):=\gamma (y)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x,y)$ exists, and $\gamma (y)$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$. Does it follows that $f(x,y)$ continuous on $[0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample. Let $$f(x,y) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    x\cdot y & \quad \text{if $x\in(0,+\infty), y\in[0,+\infty)$}\\
    -1 & \quad \text{if $x=0, y\in[0,+\infty)$ }
  \end{array} \right.$$
Then $f(x,y)$ is continuous in $(0,+\infty)\times[0,+\infty)$ and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x,y)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}x\cdot y=y\cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow0}x=y\cdot0=0=:\gamma(y)$$ for every $y$, i.e. $\gamma(y)\equiv0$ is constant and thus continuous. But since $$f(0,y)=-1\neq0=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x,y)$$ for every y, we have that $f(x,y)$ is not continuous on $[0,+\infty)\times[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: sorry, where $f(0,y):=\gamma(y)$.